# Data correlation in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, mobile, swiftui

I fairly new to SwiftUI programming so sorry in advance if this is a dumb question. I would like to build an app in SwiftUI language that, giving the possibility to the user to select two data (i.e. from a datapicker), should return their correlation.

For example: if I select 
*"Yellow"* from the first picker 
and *"Blue"* from the second one 
--> I should receive *"Green"*.

Given the assumption I know all the possible combinations (and the impossible ones) my question is: how I can store and retreive the data? Which structure I should use?

Thanks a lot for your replies.

Comment: did you check my answer are you looking for the same?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for dalay! You answer was very helpfull to bulid the initial structure for the picker of first two colors... Now I just have to figure out how to get the third color as result of them! Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Picker for selection of color after that use`@Published var`
here is some snipped code that might help you.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var first_color = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]
var second_color = ["Yellow", "White", "Green"]
@ObservedObject var color_value = Color_value()

var body: some View {
    VStack {

        Picker(selection: $color_value.first_value, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(0 ..< first_color.count) {
                Text(self.first_color[$0])
            }
        }

        Text("You selected: \(first_color[$color_value.first_value.wrappedValue])")

        Picker(selection: $color_value.second_value, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(0 ..< second_color.count) {
                Text(self.second_color[$0])
            }
        }
        Text("You selected: \(second_color[$color_value.second_value.wrappedValue])")

        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
            obj_saved_color.first_color = self.first_color[self.$color_value.first_value.wrappedValue]
            obj_saved_color.second_color = self.second_color[self.$color_value.second_value.wrappedValue]
            print(obj_saved_color.first_color)
            print(obj_saved_color.second_color)
        }, label: {
            Text("Save")
        })
    }
}
```

}

```
class Color_value: ObservableObject {
let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
var first_value = 0 { willSet { objectWillChange.send() } }
var second_value = 0 { willSet { objectWillChange.send() } }}


class saved_color: ObservableObject {
@Published var first_color: String?
@Published var second_color: String?}

let obj_saved_color = saved_color()
```

here is saved_color class @Published store value you add and Color_value class Observed change in value